# JWT и возможность авторизации под любым аккаунтом

Tags: rest, jwt

Есть многопользовательский сайт. У пользователей есть роли - admin и user. Сайт построен по принципу тонкого клиента. Фронтенд отдельно от бэкенда. Общение через REST API. Авторизация JWT. У админа в панели есть возможность смотреть список всех зареганых юзеров.

Хочу сделать для админа, возможность логинится под любым юзером. Админ нажал на кнопочку, и его перелогинило под юзером. При этом всем, нужно что бы система понимала, что перед ней обычный юзер,с одним отличием, у этого юзера есть возможность вернутся назад, в аккаунт админа.

Делал такую фичу, на обычном сайте, при перелогине, просто писал в сессию юзера флаг, parent_role = admin

А вот как провернуть такое с JWT? Сессий же нет.

Приходит на ум выдавать куку,зашифрованную.

Как быть?

Comment: Ну, просто прописать этот же флаг внутри этого же JWT?

Comment: JWT это и есть по сути зашифрованная кука.